# Server 2008 R2 Replication Small Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have two 2008 R2 Servers.

When I Connect those two Servers By Name, I Can Use Replication.

But When I Connect This Two Servers By IP Address, I Can't Use Replication.

I Get Error Like:

> SQL Server Replication Requires The Actual Server Name.....

Is replication possible through IP address in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Is it possible through Server name only ?

Comment: @@servername gives me what exactly my server-name is. There is no problem with Server name and I can do my all work with Server Names. These servers are in my LAN, Not in domain. But when i connect these servers by IP Addresses, I cant use Replication, It gives me error like "SQL Server Replication Requires The Actual Server Name....." 

So i just want to confirm that without connecting server by Server names, I can't use Replication.

Answer (score 0):

Replication is very touchy about server names. In my experience, if you try to tell it any other name than what that server thinks `@@SERVERNAME` is, it won't let you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm sure there are workarounds, which I wouldn't advise, SQL replication is made to work with Server name only. This is by design. Let's say the subscriber is on a different domain, you have 2 options. Make a DNS entry for that single server or edit your hosts file. But you won't be able to use the ip address. You basically need to find a way around that.If you could state the reason why you wouldn't be able to use the Server Name, maybe we can help you figure out a workaround.

Comment: @@servername gives me what exactly my servername is. There is no problem with Server and I can do my all work with Server Names. These servers are in my LAN, Not in domain. But when i connect these servers by IP Address, I cant use Replication, It gives me error like "SQL Server Replication Requires The Actual Server Name....." 

So i just want to confirm that without connecting server by Server names, I can't use Replication.